# Endpoint for ACF options page field WordPress REST API?

Tags: json, wordpress, rest, wordpress-rest-api, wp-api

Hope someone can help with this,

I'm building out a small plugin that will allow me to bounce a single data field to an endpoint. The data is currently stored in a ACF under an ACF options page.

I have been able to write a small plugin that allows me to retrieve ACF field content on my front end pages but I'm struggling to find out how to do that for the ACF options pages in the wp-admin area of Wordpress? Has anyone had any experience in doing so and could point me in the right direction.  No editing of fields is required simply the ability to read and spit them into the json.

As per business requirement, 3rd party plugins are unsuitable for use in this scenario.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: confirming I understand the issue... you are wanting to get ACF options page data?  Are you avoiding using the ACF `get_field` helper?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.